# Which version of the Dinkumware STL Lib ships with Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, visual-studio-2012, predefined-macro

In earlier versions of Visual Studio, there was a predefinied macro "_CPPLIB_VER" which reported the version of the Dinkumware STL Library shipped with this version of VS. As of 2012, I am unable to find or use this macro - it is undefinied and I am unable to find any information on this matter online.

Is the Dinkumware STL Lib no longer used in VS2012? Was the macro renamed?

Windows 7 x64
Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Professional

Comment: It is still there, yvals.h.  The VS2012 version is 540.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the definition of `_CPPLIB_VER` can be found in a header file named **`yvals.h`** somewhere under your VS installation folder. For Visual Studio 2010 it's in `VC\include`.

Be careful because `_CPPLIB_VER` is no longer an official predefined macro since Visual Studio 2008.

The "Change History" section of [Predefined Macros (Visual Studio 2008)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on MSDN says:

> Added Visual Studio 2008 values for `_ATL_VER`, `_MSC_VER`, `_MFC_VER`; **removed `_CPPLIB_VER`**; updated `__COUNTER__`, `_DEBUG`, `_DLL`, `_MT`, `__FUNCDNAME__`, `__FUNCSIG__`, `__FUNCTION__`, `__FILE__`. Cleaned up topic.

And the macro was one of the "Microsoft-Specific Predefined Macros" for VS 2005. See [Predefined Macros (Visual Studio 2005)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> _CPPLIB_VER
>
> Defined if you include any of the C++ Standard Library headers; reports which version of the Dinkumware header files are present.

Comment: Wow, didn't know it was dropped, since I still see it in VC2010 and VC2012 after including a C++ header. But from your answer (and its absence in the list of predefined macros, which I already wondered about) I guess it is not officially garanteed to be present anymore?

Comment: I think so. It seems that Microsoft doesn't want developers to depend on the definition of this macro...

Comment: Still defined in `yvals.h` for VS2012 but I guess it's not guaranteed anymore - still can work out if you are using the Dinkumware that comes with VS2012.