# Where is _CPPLIB_VER defined and is it modifiable in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I got an error "cannot open include file 'initializer_list', but I have not included `initializer_list` anywhere in the code.

```
#if !defined(BOOST_NO_0X_HDR_INITIALIZER_LIST)
#include <initializer_list> // error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'initializer_list': No such file or directory d:\boost\unordered\unordered_set.hpp
#endif
```

Then I use `'show includes'` options and find `BOOST_NO_0X_HDR_INITIALIZER_LIST` is in `dinkumware.hpp`:

```
//  C++0x headers implemented in 520 (as shipped by Microsoft)
//
#if !defined(_CPPLIB_VER) || _CPPLIB_VER < 520
#  define BOOST_NO_0X_HDR_INITIALIZER_LIST
#endif
```

Now I know `_CPPLIB_VER` must be defined somewhere and the value is greater than 520. Where is it and can I change the value?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286286/which-version-of-the-dinkumware-stl-lib-ships-with-visual-studio-2012

Comment: You should try updating your version of boost as [mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471340/cannot-open-include-file-initializer-list#comment20181157_14471340).

Comment: @JesseGood you are right. It works when using latest boost. But I still don't get the reason. Is it a bug in boost?

Comment: Yes, they weren't detecting MSVC's implementation correctly (although it will be great when we can write C++11 code with MSVC).

Comment: While MSDN indicates it's a 'predefined' macro, it actually seems to get set by a define in `yvals.h`, a header that's included by nearly any (if not actually any) header in the C/C++ runtime headers.  It's Dinkumware's header used to set up any baseline stuff for the library.  However, as Hans says you should fix/update boost, not the `_CPPLIB_VER` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just the version check that is wrong.  The current VS2012 C++ library version is 540, initializer lists will be supported in the next release.  Coming very soon.

The Boost team just didn't have a time machine to guess the correct version.  They picked the version number available at the time, the one for VS2010.  Albeit that they got the test wrong, 520 didn't have it either so it should have been <=.  Short from updating Boost, editing the file would have been a quick fix.